# converting string to tuple in python

Tags: python, string, tuples, eval

I have a string returnd from a software like `"('mono')"` from that I needed to convert string to tuple .

that I was thinking using `ast.literal_eval("('mono')")` but it is saying malformed string.

Comment: It needs to be properly quoted before it could be converted. E.g. `'("mono")'`

Comment: A tuple with a single element in Python needs a trailing comma, like `('mono',)`.

Comment: What kind of values do you have to read? Maybe it is a nice case for writing a regex to parse this input...

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("('mono')")` works fine both in Python 2 and Python 3, no "malformed string". What are you doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want tuples, you must expect lists of more than element in some cases. Unfortunately you don't give examples beyond the trivial `(mono)`, so we have to guess. Here's my guess:

```
"(mono)"
"(two,elements)"
"(even,more,elements)"
```

If all your data looks like this, turn it into a list by splitting the string (minus the surrounding parens), then call the tuple constructor. Works even in the single-element case:

```
assert data[0] == "(" and data[-1] == ")"
elements = data[1:-1].split(",")
mytuple = tuple(elements)
```

Or in one step: `elements = tuple(data[1:-1].split(","))`.
If your data **doesn't** look like my examples, edit **your question** to provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

How about using regular expressions ?

```
In [1686]: x
Out[1686]: '(mono)'

In [1687]: tuple(re.findall(r'[\w]+', x))
Out[1687]: ('mono',)

In [1688]: x = '(mono), (tono), (us)'

In [1689]: tuple(re.findall(r'[\w]+', x))
Out[1689]: ('mono', 'tono', 'us')

In [1690]: x = '(mono, tonous)'

In [1691]: tuple(re.findall(r'[\w]+', x))
Out[1691]: ('mono', 'tonous')
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert string to tuple? Just apply `tuple`:

```
>>> tuple('(mono)')
('(', 'm', 'o', 'n', 'o', ')')
```

Now it's a tuple.

Comment: If you're intentionally being snarky, I'm amused ;-). But I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP is after...

Comment: @alexis I'm fullfilling every single requirement he has stated!!!!11!!1 And if one person is amused, then I already achieved half my goal. If it makes one person realize that it's important to say what you want, I achieved the other half.

Comment: Yes, you are. It's kinda like those "please photoshop the Eiffel Tower under my finger" memes.

Comment: @alexis I love those! (but I didn't realize that's what I was doing :-)

Comment: I actually wanted this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
a = ('mono')
print tuple(a)      # <-- you create a tuple from a sequence 
                    #(which is a string)
print tuple([a])    # <-- you create a tuple from a sequence 
                    #(which is a list containing a string)
print tuple(list(a))# <-- you create a tuple from a sequence 
                    #     (which you create from a string)
print (a,)# <-- you create a tuple containing the string
print (a)
```

Output :

```
('m', 'o', 'n', 'o')
('mono',)
('m', 'o', 'n', 'o')
('mono',)
mono
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the desired output is a tuple with a single string: ('mono',)

A tuple of one has a trailing comma in the form (tup,)

```
a = '(mono)'
a = a[1:-1] # 'mono': note that the parenthesis are removed removed 
            # if they are inside the quotes they are treated as part of the string!
b = tuple([a]) 
b
> ('mono',)
# the final line converts the string to a list of length one, and then the list to a tuple
```